# How can i send several request (http method: PUT) to a single endpoint

Tags: json, rest, api, csv, postman

I have access to a specific endpoint and i want to send several request to it at once but i am not 100% sure how to do that. I need to update several information related to different products so **i need to specify the product within the endpoint**, i mean, i.e:

If you access this particular endpoint: **{{URL_API}}/products/** you will get all the products **but** i need to specify the product that i want to update:

> {{URL_API}}/products/99RE345GT

Take a look at this, i want to send a JSON like this:

```
{
    "sku": "99RE345GT",
    "price": "56665.0000",
    "status": 1,
    "group_prices": [
        {
            "group": "CLASS A",
            "price": 145198.794
        },
        {
            "group": "CLASS B",
            "price": 145198.794
        },
        {
            "group": "CLASS C",
            "price": 145198.794
        }
    ]
}
```

AND another one like this (**both JSONs share the same structure BUT with different information**):

```
{
    "sku": "98PA345GT",
    "price": "17534.0000",
    "status": 1,
    "group_prices": [
        {
            "group": "CLASS A",
            "price": 145198.794
        },
        {
            "group": "CLASS B",
            "price": 145198.794
        },
        {
            "group": "CLASS C",
            "price": 145198.794
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i do that?.I have already generated more than 200 JSONs for every product..

So, i have to update 200 products so i generated one JSON for every product, do you get me?

Following my example i would need to edit (somehow) the endpoint for every product and send a JSON, i.e:

since the first JSON has the SKU: 99RE345GT it should perform a **http method: PUT** over this enpoint:

> {{URL_API}}/products/99RE345GT

Then, since the second JSON has the SKU: 98PA345GT it should perform a **http method: PUT** over this enpoint:

> {{URL_API}}/products/98PA345GT

I have never done something like this before.. i read something about CSV + POSTMAN runner but i did not understand the way.

Can you help me?

EDIT:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

NEW UPDATE, if i use GET it throws "200" but i have to perform a PUT method:

[image: image5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without having access to your API docs or any indication which information is changing, i've made the following assumptions:

1. the PUT endpoint requires the SKU id in the endpoint
2. price, status, class A price, class B price, class C price are variables that are changing

first up create your request like so... identifying the variables.
[image]

next create your CSV file, making sure to use field/column names that match the variables.
[image]

final step, open Collection Runner and click Select File. once you've selected your CSV file, the `iterations` field will update with the number of rows in the file.
[image]

from there you just run your request and Postman will iterate through your file updating the products using the info in your CSV file.

Comment: Hey dude, how are you?
It keeps on throwing this error: 404 Not Found (i have edited my thread)

Comment: I guess the problem is the endpoint: {{URL_API}}/ns/products/{{sku}}.. it does not recognize the address. {{sku}} = unresolved variable

Comment: @Student_new - are you meant to have `ns` in your `PUT` endpoint? typically your endpoint stays the same regardless of the verb, and your `GET` doesn't use it.

Comment: Yes, i have to use the ns word.
If i use this endpoint: {{URL_API}}/ns/products/:{{sku}} (using *:* ) it throws this error message: *Multi-Status (WebDAV) (RFC 4918)* but i use this endpoint (without *:*) it throws *404 not found* :(

Comment: @Why did you say: "GET"? I have to use a PUT http method :/

Comment: Pal, can you take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60878237/defining-a-new-variable-in-order-to-make-a-huge-iteration-giving-me-an-error

Comment: i fully understood that you needed to `PUT` data but your comment "If you access this particular endpoint: {{URL_API}}/products/ you will get all the products but i need to specify the product that i want to update:" is based on the endpoint being a `GET` request. i was merely trying to understand why your `GET` endpoint didn't use `ns` yet your `PUT` did. its part of trying to understand why yours didn't work but mine did. i see from your re-asking that it's simply because you didn't use a C(omma)S(eparated)V(alue) file.