# Sending a request without specifying the fields in the body

Tags: csv, postman, endpoint

I'm trying to send several PUT request to a specific endpoint.

I am using a CSV file within the columns and values, the name of the different columns reference the different variables inside the body, do you get me?

This is the endpoint:

> {{URL_API}}/products/{{sku}} --sku is the id of the product, i created that variable because i use it to pass the reference

This is the body that i use:

```
{
    "price":"{{price}}",
    "tax_percentage":"{{tax_percentage}}",
    "store_code":"{{store_code}}",
    "markup_top":"{{markup_top}}",
    "status":"{{status}}",
    "group_prices": [
        {
            "group":"{{class_a}}",
            "price":"{{price_a}}",
            "website":"{{website_a}}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't want to use the body anymore.. sometimes some products have more tan 1 group of prices, i mean:

```
    "group_prices": [
        {
            "group":"{{class_a}}",
            "price":"{{price_a}}",
            "website":"{{website_a}}"
        },
        {
            "group":"{{class_b}}",
            "price":"{{price_b}}",
            "website":"{{website_b}}"
        }
```

Is it possible to create something like this in the CSV file?

> sku,requestBody
>
> 99RE345GT, {JSON Payload}

How should i declare the {JSON Payload}?

Can you help me?

EDIT:
This is the CSV file i used:

> sku,price,tax_percentage,store_code,markup_top,status,class_a,price_a,website_a
>   95LB645R34ER,147000,US-21,B2BUSD,1.62,1,CLASS A,700038.79,B2BUSD

I want to pass the JSON within the CSV file, i mean

> sku,requestBody
>
> 95LB645R34ER,{"price":"147000","tax_percentage":"US-21","store_code":"B2BUSD","markup_top":"1.62","status":"1","group_prices":
>   [{ "group":"CLASS A","price":"700038.79","website":"B2BUSD"}]}

Is it okay?Should i specify anything on the request body or not? I read the documentation posted in POSTMAN website but i did not find an example like this.

Comment: That example is not a CSV file, it's an excel sheet. What have you tried so far? What research have you done? Writing a question that's basically a collection of other answers you have been given, isn't how Stackoverflow works. It's not a code writing service. Yes it is possible to do something like that in CSV file and is a question that has been asked before.

Comment: Hey Danny, how are you?Yeah, i know it is an Excel sheet but i only wanted to show the idea; sorry, my bad.. i new to this topic and i get  confused easily :/. I only wanted to know if it was possible to "insert" a JSON Payload inside the CSV file without using a predefined body in POSTMAN

Comment: You have a CSV file you created from a previous question. I know, because I showed you. Cut down and edit your question to include the specific details, you don't need to write out a lengthy explanation that doesn't really explain the issue. Think quality over quantity. :)

Comment: Oh, thanks Danny. Sorry for the misunderstanding :(

Comment: Ready, Danny. I've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using `JSON` data as a payload, I would use a JSON file rather than a CSV file in the Collection Runner. Use this as a template and save it as `data.json`, it's in the correct format accepted in the Runner.

```
[
    {
        "sku": "95LB645R34ER",
        "payload": {
            "price": "147000",
            "tax_percentage": "US-21",
            "store_code": "B2BUSD",
            "markup_top": "1.62",
            "status": "1",
            "group_prices": [
                {
                    "group": "CLASS A",
                    "price": "700038.79",
                    "website": "B2BUSD"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "sku": "MADEUPSKU",
        "payload": {
            "price": "99999",
            "tax_percentage": "UK-99",
            "store_code": "BLAH",
            "markup_top": "9.99",
            "status": "5",
            "group_prices": [
                {
                    "group": "CLASS B",
                    "price": "88888.79",
                    "website": "BLAH"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

In the `pre-request Script` of the request, add this code. It's creating a new `local` variable from the data under the `payload` key in the data file. The data needs to be transformed into a string so it's using `JSON.stringify()` to do this.

```
pm.variables.set("JSONpayload", JSON.stringify(pm.iterationData.get('payload'), null, 2));
```

In the `Request Body`, add this:

```
{{JSONpayload}}
```

In the `Collection Runner`, select the Collection you would like to run and then select the `data.json` file that you previously created. Run the Collection.

[image: Collection Runner]

Comment: Hey Danny, i was checking you code; i do not fully understand why you set the value = 2. what would've happened if you had set the value = 3.. i mean, pm.variables.set("JSONpayload", JSON.stringify(pm.iterationData.get('payload'), null, 3));
Also, i *will* follow your idea but i would like to know the way to do that by using CSV, do you get me?

Comment: It is just being used to 'pretty print' the JSON so it reads better in the runner, remove the null and the number at it will still work the same. The number relates to the spacing. To be honest, you can easily just do a search for that - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify This is a method of doing it via JSON, doing it via CSV will work in exactly the same way but I'll let you figure that out instead of telling you the answer.